# auto vs auto&& for a function return value

Tags: c++, function, c++11, return-value, auto

Could you tell me please whether I am right that use of auto&& for a function return value is always a better choice than use of auto. For instance, in

```
auto val = someObj.getVal();
```

the val will be a copy if getVal() returns a reference. However, use of the universal reference auto&& does not have such a disadvantage? The only information I need to know is whether getVal() is const or not.

Comment: you don't need to know whether `getVal` is const. `auto&&` is a forwarding reference; it will deduce to `T const &` if `getVal` is a const lvalue for example.

Answer (score 6):

> However, use of the universal reference auto&& does not have such a disadvantage?

No, it would not copy the return value.

### The problem

However, sometimes copy is necessary, and using `auto&&` for both `prvalue` and references can create dangling references. Consider this case:

```
struct A {
    // A: Another programmer changed it from:
    // int getVal() { return mInteger; }

    // B
    int &getVal() { return mInteger; }

private:
    int mInteger;
};

int main() {
    A *a = new A;

    auto   integerCopy = a->getVal();

    // int& on case B, int&& on case A.
    auto&& integerRvalueRef  = a->getVal();

    delete a;

    // Ok, no matter what getVal returns.
    std::cout << integerCopy;
    // Dangling Reference dereference if getVal returns a reference. 
    std::cout << integerRvalueRef;
}
```

As you can see, with `auto`, there was no problem with changing of this return value. However, with `auto&&`, it has created a dangling reference.

### Conclusion

Use `auto&&` like a regular reference: treat it with caution. Using it for both `prvalue` and reference value return values may cause bad surprises.

Comment: Both approaches have their own advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: @AlexKoshulyan As long as you use it only with references, it is OK. In most cases, there is not overhead with `auto` and `prvalue` (There is no copy or move: the function will initialize its return value on the callee variable in first place).

Comment: Why not using `const auto&` for object return types? As in this case there is no need for RVO as the life time of the object within the function to return is extended.

Comment: @DrumM it won't matter for this example (it would be the same as `auto&&`). There is no "universal" way since `const auto&` won't extend the lifetime of a `lvalue`.